# My kitchen outlets are starting to wear out.

Tags: electrical

My home outlets are starting to wear out.  While I am making arrangements for replacement, I want to use a multi-outlet adapter.  The one I already tried does not work, even though it works in a different location.  Do I need to look for some specific features?

Comment: Define 'wear out", "adapter", and "does not work". It sounds like you have answered your own question and the outlet is too damaged to make a reliable connection..

Comment: This must be the next thing in the home automation...  "Power on Kitchen outlet number two Alexa"....  "Dan I am tired, would you mind using another outlet."

Comment: If the outlets aren't reliable, STOP USING THEM NOW unless you like house fires.  Outlets are quite easy to change, and it *boggles my mind* to delay the work *so long* that shopping for adapters even makes sense.  Go down to Home Depot and shop for replacement outlets!  For now, replace in-kind.  If it's a plain outlet use the $4 commercial-grade jobs not the 60 cent tenant grade cheapies (which is the one your "arrangement" will use.  Knowing it's done right is the best reason to DIY.)

Answer (score 1):

In many kitchens (In USA/Canada, anyway) kitchen outlets are wired as a MWBC with the two receptacles operating on different legs of the service. Rather than being at the same voltage, the hots on each half of the outlet are 240 volts apart (120 from neutral for each.)

If your "multi-outlet-adapter" internally wires the hots together (rather than feeding half of it's receptacles from one, and half from the other) it will presumably make a large nasty spark and hopefully trip the breaker when you plug it in.

Most adapters don't comment on how they are wired internally. Wiring the hots together would in general be a bad idea (as MWBCs to split outlets are not uncommon) and as such might be rare in well-designed products, but not all products are well-designed.

If you are replacing the outlets (receptacles) anyway, it might be worth replacing them with ones that don't need an adapter to give you more receptacles, or to add additional outlet boxes if you are finding the current outlets insufficient to your daily needs.

Comment: I'd strengthen the "worth replacing them with ones that don't need an adaptor". If you're replacing your outlets, you should end up with a configuration that fully supports your expected needs, WITHOUT the need for (at least somewhat) ugly and (at least somewhat) dangerous plug-in adaptors.

Comment: Except if they're in the kitchen, they must now be GFCI.  GFCI+MWBC is expensive to deal with.

Comment: You can deal with that with minimal rewiring two ways - use normal GFCIs and put every other one on (red) or (black), passing the other through the box with a wirenut. Or double your boxes so you have two-gangs and two GFCIs, in each, one on (red) and one on (black)